# How to use os.path.getsize() with * in python?

Tags: python

There's a directory : /home/zurelsoft/files
 with the file names `.sachitadhFebruary28,2013,18:45PMsolexa.zip.M9mw9e`

There are lots of files like this:

```
.sachitadhFebruary28,2013,18:45PMsolexa.zip.M
.sachitadhFebruary28,2013,18:45PMsolexa.zip.KK
```

which are stored in a database.

```
    current_file = Queue.objects.all()
      j = [i.file_session for i in current_file]
        k = [str(i) for i in j]
        new_file_size = [int(os.path.getsize(i+'*')) for i in k]
```

I am trying to get the filsize like this but I am getting No such directory error.

I found `glob.glob()` used that but didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: /home/zurelsoft/files is a directory name and all those files are under it. See my updated question.

Comment: "I found `glob.glob()` used that but didn't work." The only answer for "didn't work" is "do it right". It has the same level of detail... What did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getsize` takes *exactly one* filename - and anything you give it is assumed to be exactly a filename. To get the expansion you want, you do want to use `glob.glob` - presumably, it didn't work because you did something like:

```
os.path.getsize(glob.glob('/home/zurelsoft/*'))
```

Which will always give an exception, since `glob` doesn't return the exactly one filename that `getsize` expects - it returns a list of all the matches. Iterate over that list to get each individual one - eg,

```
for filename in glob.glob('/home/zurelsoft/*'):
   print(os.path.getsize(filename))
```

will print the size of every file in your home directory.

Comment: I have list as a argument for glob.glob()? And it's not working.

Comment: @user2032220 it is the same pattern again: `glob` takes a *single* pattern (as a string), and gives you back a list of all the filenames that match it. If you have a list of patterns that you want to resolve, you'll need to pass each element individually to `glob` by iterating over it.

Comment: Yeah done but I want the answer in list comprehension: Can you please answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150458/how-to-convert-this-for-loop-in-list-comprehension