# How to convert this for loop in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I have a for loop like this:

```
for i in conversion:
    for f in glob.glob(i):
        print(os.path.getsize(f))
```

I want to convert this into list comprehension:

Tried this:

```
[os.path.getsize(f) for f in glob.glob(i) for i in conversion]
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The order of the `for` loops in a double list comprehension is the *same* order that you would use with nested loops:

```
[os.path.getsize(f) for i in conversion for f in glob.glob(i)]
```

It's a bit confusing because you expect the inner loop to be more "inner", but once you realize it is the same order as the nested loop, everything is easy :)

Comment: i am having problem while adding if statement instead of next for loop.

`james_unique = [term for term in james if term not in james_unique]`