# How to convert nested loop to list comprehension?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, big-o, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I'm attempting to solve an algorithm question.

#### Given an array, count the number of inversions it has. Do this faster than O(N^2) time.

my first solution which doesn't satisfy O(N^2) uses nested loops:

```
def getInvCount(arr, n): 

    inv_count = 0
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(i + 1, n): 
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]): 
                inv_count += 1

    return inv_count
```

My attempt at converting to a list comprehension

```
def getInvCount(arr, n):
    inv_count = 0    
    inv_count = [j for i in range (n) for j in range(i + 1, n) if (arr[i] > arr[j])]
    inv_count += 1
    return inv_count
```

I'm basing my solution on this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/)

I understand I'm not getting my syntax correctly, especially `inv_count += 1` I have looked for examples where the nested loop needs to return a count and is written using list comprehension but I couldn't find any.

Ideally, the function should tell the number of inversions in an array like so;

```
def getInvCount(arr, n): 

    inv_count = 0
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(i + 1, n): 
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]): 
                inv_count += 1

    return inv_count

#testdata

arr = [1, 20, 6, 4, 5] 
n = len(arr) 
print("Number of inversions are", getInvCount(arr, n))
```

#### Output

```
Number of inversions are 5
```

with my current solution

```
def getInvCount(arr, n):
    inv_count = 0    
    inv_count = [j for i in range (n) for j in range(i + 1, n) if (arr[i] > arr[j])]
    inv_count += 1
    return inv_count

#testdata

arr = [1, 20, 6, 4, 5] 
n = len(arr) 
print("Number of inversions are", getInvCount(arr, n))
```

#### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "and.py", line 24, in <module>
    getInvCount(arr, n)) 
  File "and.py", line 16, in getInvCount
    inv_count += 1
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Converting nested `for` loops to a comprehension with multiple `for`s won't improve this in terms of Big-O.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)?

Comment: return sum([1 if (arr[i] > arr[j]) else 0 for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1,n)]) should work but won't be more efficient in terms of complexity

Comment: thanks a lot @foxpal this helps me understand complexity very well.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I didn't understand complexity very well, but Reddit has put me through ELI5 style, you are correct, it doesn't help since the goal is to reduce the for loops not add them to one line.

Comment: @AurghoBhattacharjee thank you! the list comprehension works! if you put that as an answer I will accept, as for the complexity bit, I'm understanding more of it daily and foxpal has linked a resource that explains it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum([1 if (arr[i] > arr[j]) else 0 for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1,n)])
```

should work as a list comprehension answer. I had referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150458/how-to-convert-this-for-loop-in-list-comprehension) stackoverflow post a few months ago to do be able to do this.

In terms of time complexity, however, it won't be better than O(N^2).